# The type 'System.Data.Linq.Binary' is not supported in aggregation operations

Tags: linq-to-sql

```
var query2 = (from p in db.posts
                     where (p.date) == (from q in db.posts
                                        select q.date).Max()
                     select p.date).SingleOrDefault();

id = Convert.ToInt32(query2);
```

I'm getting this error when trying to get the max Date from posts table, is there an alternative way?

Comment: Are you sure p.date has a datetyme type?

Comment: thanks for ur reply,
It is stored as a timestamp in the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TIMESTAMP` is an internal SQL Server [datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631%28SQL.80%29.aspx) stored as a 8-byte blob. It has nothing to do with date/time - it's just an internal counter, really.

It's actually deprecated even - use the `rowversion` datatype instead (as of SQL Server 2008 and up).

From SQL Server Books online:

> The SQL Server timestamp data type has
>   nothing to do with times or dates. SQL
>   Server timestamps are binary numbers
>   that indicate the relative sequence in
>   which data modifications took place in
>   a database. The timestamp data type
>   was originally implemented to support
>   the SQL Server recovery algorithms.

You cannot use byte array bytes in aggregates, as the error message says clearly.

I would assume there is another `DATETIME` column in your table somewhere??

Check out this excellent [Timestamps vs. Datetime data types](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/timestamps-vs-datetime-data-types) article for more insights.

Marc

Comment: I changed from timestamp to Datetime and it worked.
I'm new to LINQ/Sql and in MYsql timestamp worked fine.
Thanks for ur answer

Comment: @Joe: no problem. Yes, the name "TIMESTAMP" can be quite misleading! That's why they're changing it to "ROWVERSION" - seems more intuitive